# How would I do this in a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm being told that my lucky numbers math.random code is repetitive code and to combine it with the output string or user a for loop. How would i do this in a for loop?

```js
function showFortune() {
    // Quotes to grab from array.
    var quotes = new Array(5)
    quotes[0] = "The road to riches is paved with homework.";
    quotes[1] = "Ignore your previous fortune.";
    quotes[2] = "Avoid taking unnecessary gambles.";
    quotes[3] = "You love peace.";
    quotes[4] = "A friend asks only for your time and not your money.";

    // Spacer for between numbers
    var space = ('      ')

    // Get random lucky numbers
    var number1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60 + 1);
    var number2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60 + 1);
    var number3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60 + 1);
    var number4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60 + 1);
    var number5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60 + 1);
    var number6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60 + 1);

    // Get a number for picking the quote
    var rand_int = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

    // Show the quote & number
    document.getElementById("fortuneArea").innerHTML = (quotes[rand_int] + "<br />" + "Lucky numbers:" + space + "<b>" + number1 + space + number2 + space + number3 + space + number4 + space + number5 + space + number6 + "</b>");

  } // end function
```

```css
b {
  color: #FF0000;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Show my fortune!" onclick="showFortune();" />
  </p>
</form>
<div id="fortuneArea"></div>
```

Comment: You should use an array of random numbers.

Comment: You should definitely put this in a function: `function getRandInt(n) { return Math.floor(Math.random() * n + 1); }` then... `var number1 = getRandInt(60);`

Comment: Hint: Identify places where you are doing the same thing over and over, and use a loop to do them.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but the browser will normalize whitespace in your html.  Adding 100 spaces is the same as a single space, so your `space`variable is kind of a waste.

Comment: JLRishe I suck at for loops i wouldn't know the first thing  to do.

Comment: @WilfredoTurner Start with something simple. How to create a function. How to create a loop. Etc.

Comment: offtopic: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code can be optimised in multiple places.. Let's do it bit by bit:

First of all, comments in JavaScript are shown with `//` tags, not `<!-- -->`. The later is used for HTML. ;-)

Using multiple spaces like that, is never a good thing. Use CSS for that. A good way would be by putting your "number" in a `span` element.

Generating the numbers is repetitive, so we can loop that. Let's do all this together now:

```
//We will fill this variable with the text of numbers.
var numberString = "";

//We're gonna loop 6 times: from 0 to 5.
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
   var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60 + 1); 
   numberString += "<span>" + number + "</span>";
}

//Quote number:
var rand_int = Math.floor(Math.random()*5); 

//And now everything together:
document.getElementById("fortuneArea").innerHTML=(quotes[rand_int]+"<br />"+"<span>Lucky numbers:</span><b>" + numberString + "</b>");
```

Only thing left to do is add this in your css:

```
span {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could change this:

```
// Get random lucky numbers
var number1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60 + 1);
var number2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60 + 1);
var number3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60 + 1);
var number4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60 + 1);
var number5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60 + 1);
var number6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60 + 1);
```

To this:

```
var numbers = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    numbers.push((Math.floor(Math.random() * 60 + 1)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to rephrase... You want 6 lucky numbers between 1 and 60.

Instead of storing in 6 independent variables, stick em into an array.

```
var lucky = [];
for (var l = 0; l < 6; l++) {
    lucky.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 60 + 1));
}
```

or

```
var lucky = new Array(6);
for (var l = 0; l < lucky.length; l++) {
    lucky.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 60 + 1));
}
```

Should do the trick. Also, I know you didn't ask but

```
var rand_int = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
```

would be a lot better as

```
var rand_int = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
```

That way if/when you add more quotes you don't have to redo your code. Keep trucking friend, coding is fun.

--edit

Whoops, forgot the output. Instead of

```
number1 + space + number2
```

do a join. lucky.join(' ') will give you exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function showFortune() {
    // Quotes to grab from array.
    var quotes = new Array(5)
    quotes[0] = "The road to riches is paved with homework.";
    quotes[1] = "Ignore your previous fortune.";
    quotes[2] = "Avoid taking unnecessary gambles.";
    quotes[3] = "You love peace.";
    quotes[4] = "A friend asks only for your time and not your money.";

    // Spacer for between numbers
    var space = ('      ')

    var numbers ="";
    // Get random lucky numbers
    for (i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
      numbers+= Math.floor(Math.random() * 60 + 1) + space;
    }

    // Get a number for picking the quote
    var rand_int = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

    // Show the quote & number
    document.getElementById("fortuneArea").innerHTML = (quotes[rand_int] + "<br />" + "Lucky numbers:" + space + "<b>" + numbers+ "</b>");

  } // end function
```

```html
<div id="fortuneArea"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first of all bind your strings to an array by default, rather than each individually.

```
var quotes = ["The road to riches is paved with homework.", "Ignore your previous fortune.", "Avoid taking unnecessary gambles.", "You love peace.", "A friend asks only for your time and not your money."];
```

Then you'll want to create an array, loop through (I set the number at < 6, so 0,1,2,3,4,5) a set of numbers, and then push items into the array.

```
// Get random lucky numbers
var numbers = [];
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    numbers.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 60 + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a lucky numbers function you need to check for duplicates

```
function showFortune() {

    var quotes = ["The road to riches is paved with homework.",
                  "Ignore your previous fortune.",
                  "Avoid taking unnecessary gambles.",
                  "You love peace.",
                  "A friend asks only for your time and not your money."];

    var numbers = [];

    var counter = 0;

    do 
    {
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60 + 1);

        if (numbers.indexOf(num) == -1) // if the array doesn't already contain number
        {
            // add the unique number to the array
            numbers.push(num);
            counter++; 
        }

    } while (counter < 6);


    var output = ""; // Build html string from numbers

    for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
        output += "<span>" + numbers[i] + "</span>"
    }

    var rand_int = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

    // Show the quote & number
    document.getElementById("fortuneArea").innerHTML = 
       (quotes[rand_int] + "<br />" + "Lucky numbers:" + output);
}
```

with your spacing set in your CSS

```
span {
    padding-left: 10px;
    paddding-right: 10px;
}
```

This will help browsers to display it properly.

array.indexOf is not supported in IE 8 and below BTW

Answer (score 0):

Just another way:

```js
function showFortune(){
    var quotes = [
            "The road to riches is paved with homework.",
            "Ignore your previous fortune.",
            "Avoid taking unnecessary gambles.",
            "You love peace.",
            "A friend asks only for your time and not your money."
        ],
        // Use an element to which you can give a CSS width
        space = '<i class="spacer"></i>',
        i = 6,
        // Use the 'rand()' function created below
        result = rand(quotes) + '<br />' + 'Lucky numbers:' + '<b>';

        while(i--){ result += space + rand(60); }

        document.getElementById("fortuneArea").innerHTML = result + '</b>';
}

function rand(param){
    if(param.length){ return param[ Math.floor(Math.random() * param.length) ]; }
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * param + 1);
}
```

```css
b { color: #FF0000; font-weight: normal; } .spacer{ display: inline-block; width: 1.5em; }
```

```html
<form action="">
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Show my fortune!" onclick="showFortune();" />
  </p>
</form>
<div id="fortuneArea"></div>
```